# Can a Arraylist contain subclasses of a class?Check what subclasses type in a Arraylist?

Tags: java

For example, I have class A and its subclasses B and C. I have an Arraylist contains class A's objects. The Arraylist can contain objects from class B and C? I have a foreach loop looping thought the Arraylist. How to check the object is Class A, B or C?

I think the Arraylist can. But I don't know how to do in question 2. I don't know what to try

Comment: Yes you can, Yes you can.

Comment: The The Java™ Tutorials from Oracle has a trait about [Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) || using newer Java versions you can also use [Pattern Matching for instanceof](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394) and [Pattern Matching for switch](https://openjdk.org/jeps/441)